# Mr Cool Remote Control Checksum Algorithm

Tags: checksum

For fun I've decided to reverse engineer the Mr Cool IR Remote, and build my own version of it.

I've been able to capture the IR sequence for a lot of different button presses. It appears to use a coding scheme similar to the NEC standard, the main difference being it appears to be Msb first. I think it is Msb first because the byte that I think represents the temperature changes logically if I assume Msb first, if I assume Lsb first then it is not as logical. Below is a table of values I've captured along with the associated button press. What I can't make heads or tails of is how the last byte, which I assume is a checksum, is calculated. I've tried various combinations of sums and XOR and haven't gotten it. Any help/tips or tricks for figuring out the algorithm to calculate the last byte would be greatly appreciated. Note, I tried to ask ChatGPT and Bard AI to help and they were laughably bad, so hopefully us normal humans can figure this out!

[image: Button Presses and associated values]

Comment: Here are the values if you want to copy and paste, in multi posts due to character limit:
A1826AFFFF67
A18269FFFF65
A18268FFFF64
A18267FFFF6A
A18266FFFF6B
A18265FFFF69
A18264FFFF68
A1A06AFFFF44
A1A069FFFF47
A1A068FFFF46
A1A067FFFF49
A1A066FFFF48
A1A065FFFF4B
A1A064FFFF4A
A1886AFFFF68
A18869FFFF6B
A18868FFFF6A
A18867FFFF61
A18866FFFF60
A18865FFFF63
A18864FFFF62
A1906AFFFF78
A19069FFFF7B
A19068FFFF7A
A19067FFFF71
A19066FFFF70
A19065FFFF73
A19064FFFF72
A1986AFFFF70
A19869FFFF73
A19868FFFF72
A19867FFFF7E
A19866FFFF7F
A19865FFFF7D
A19864FFFF7C
A1816AFFFF65

Comment: A18169FFFF66
A18168FFFF67
A18167FFFF68
A18166FFFF69
A18165FFFF6A
A18164FFFF6B
A1A36AFFFF46
A1A369FFFF44
A1A368FFFF45
A1A367FFFF4B
A1A366FFFF4A
A1A365FFFF48
A1A364FFFF49
A18B6AFFFF6A
A18B69FFFF68
A18B68FFFF69
A18B67FFFF63
A18B66FFFF62
A18B65FFFF60
A18B64FFFF61
A1936AFFFF7A
A19369FFFF78
A19368FFFF79
A19367FFFF73
A19366FFFF72
A19365FFFF70
A19364FFFF71
A19B6AFFFF72
A19B69FFFF70
A19B68FFFF71
A19B67FFFF7D
A19B66FFFF7C
A19B65FFFF7F
A19B64FFFF7E
A1A47EFFFF5B
A18C7EFFFF73
A1947EFFFF6B
A19C7EFFFF63
A202FFFFFF7E
A208FFFFFF75
A212FFFFFF6E
A213FFFFFF6F

Comment: A201FFFFFF7C
A209FFFFFF74
A20DFFFFFF70
A4A0697F2A77

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this IR protocol documented in [IRremoteESP8266](https://github.com/crankyoldgit/IRremoteESP8266#readme) in the source code files [ir_Midea.h](https://github.com/crankyoldgit/IRremoteESP8266/blob/master/src/ir_Midea.h) and [ir_Midea.cpp](https://github.com/crankyoldgit/IRremoteESP8266/blob/master/src/ir_Midea.cpp). The parts of the code I focused on were the [struct definition](https://github.com/crankyoldgit/IRremoteESP8266/blob/master/src/ir_Midea.h#L74) and the [calcChecksum function](https://github.com/crankyoldgit/IRremoteESP8266/blob/master/src/ir_Midea.cpp#L499).

In the struct definition, the bytes are ordered with the checksum first, so the bytes in the struct are in the reverse order compared to the bytes in your list. However within each byte, the bits appear to be ordered in the same way as your list. (The struct uses C bit fields. The colon numbers indicate how many bits each value uses. It appears this code expects the compiler to build the bit fields starting from the least significant bit of each byte. And it appears the `:0` happens to skip over the remaining bits of the byte it appears in.)

The checksum method used in the code is the following:

- Reverse the bit order of each byte.
- Flip the bits of each byte.
- Sum all the bytes including the checksum byte.
- The sum should be 0, modulo 256 decimal.

When I use this checksum method with your data, every row of your data gives the same sum of decimal 250 (or hex FA or binary 11111010) instead of 0.

Instead, if I remove the step that flips all the bits, then the resulting method works with your data:

- Reverse the bit order of each byte.
- Sum all the bytes including the checksum byte.
- The sum should be 0, modulo 256 decimal.

Comment: Awesome, I've confirmed this, thanks for your help. I had looked through many of the brands on IRremoteESP8266, but obviously missed the Midea! Thanks again!